# Output remote server stream bash file with line breaks on page PHP

Tags: php, bash, ssh

I am attempting to output a remote bash file onto a page so the user can see what is happening. I am able to read the bash file, however, anything I try it isn't adding a newline between each echo statements. Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is my bash file:

scirpt.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'touch /tmp/testfile'."\n"
echo "I am up\n"
echo '\n'
echo "\n"
echo
echo 'hello there'
```

Here is my php logic:

main.php

```
if(isset($_POST['option']) && $_POST['option'] == 1) { 
                $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, "/tmp/user/testscripts/up.sh");
                stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
                $stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
                $output = stream_get_contents($stream_out);

           }
....
....
....

<div class="box1">
  <form method="post">
    <label class="col">Up/Down</label>
    <span class="col">
      <input type="radio" name="option" id="r1" value="1" />
      <label for="r1">Up</label>
      <input type="radio" name="option" id="r2" value="2" />
      <label for="r2">Down</label> 
    </span>
    <span class="col">
      <input type="submit" class="button"/>
    </span>
  </form>

  <?php
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>"
  ?>
```

Here is my output on the page:

touch /tmp/testfile.\n I am in up\n \n \n hello there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bash `echo` appends a newline unless suppressed with `-n`, so don't include them.  There is a `-e` option to have `echo` interpret escaped characters but you don't need that here.

Also, to display on a web page (HTML) you will need to wrap in `<pre></pre>` tags or use the PHP `nl2br()`.

So use:

```
echo 'touch /tmp/testfile'
echo 'I am up'
echo
echo
echo
echo 'hello there'
```

Or:

```
echo 'touch /tmp/testfile
I am up


hello there'
```

HTML doesn't render newlines so this treats it as pre-formatted text that will:

```
echo '<pre>' . stream_get_contents($stream_out) . '</pre>';
```

Or convert the newlines to the HTML `<br>` tags:

```
echo nl2br(stream_get_contents($stream_out));
```

Comment: It was weird, cause it wasn't working on the PHP-HTML file but when i used ajax to post the php script it worked.

Answer (score 1):

When you echo something you'll get a *literal* version of it. C-style `\n` isn't an option.

Two options. The first is:

```
echo 'touch /tmp/testfile'
echo 'I am up'
echo
echo
echo
echo 'hello there'
```

Section option is a HEREDOC supplied to `cat`:

```
cat <<END
touch /tmp/testfile
I am up


hello there
END
```

Comment: I tried your first and second option and it still doesn't show the line breaks this is the string on the page "touch /tmp/testfile I am in up hello there"

Comment: Try it on the command-line by saving that into a `.sh` shell file. Works for me here. Not sure what results you're getting.

Comment: It is working now. It was weird, cause it wasn't working when I put the PHP-HTML code in one file without using ajax, but when I used ajax to post the PHP script from bash output it works.